# iOS Mobile Fullscreen Enable Workaround

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, safari

I have a web app and for best user experience, I need to hide the toolbar of mobile safari (iOS) .

I know that many websites use an overlay taller than the screen size and some kind of indication for the user to scroll up (like a "swipe up" gif"). Scrolling causes the toolbar to disappear!

But I was wondering if there is any library that already does this and detects if the user is playing on iOS and if he is not in fullscreen mode, triggers the popup, etc. and then hides it when the user is back in fullscreen.
If there is no library, any recommendations are welcome to detect if we have iOS and if user is not in fullscreen mode and how to hide the popup after he triggered fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how we can detect the operation system, but JavaScript does have a fullscreen API that you could use to detect if the user is using fullscreen, and then you could hide the toolbar accordingly.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/api_fullscreen.asp